# Bootstrap Pull Right Sub-Navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically my issue is that I'm trying to pull this to the right of the page and have no idea how this would be done;

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/account.php">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">6</a></li>

    ! - This is the one that i need aligned to the right - !

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Admin Panel</a></li>

</ul>
```

This is the sub-menu under the navigation bar I use the default `bootstrap CSS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class "pull-right" i'm making a fiddle for you.
 https://jsfiddle.net/7Lwa0mky/

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/account.php">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">6</a></li>

<!--This is the one that i need aligned to the right -->

<li role="presentation" class="pull-right"><a href="#">Admin Panel</a></li>
```

Comment: @Peanuts no problem, its funny that you totally used the correct terminology :) added a fiddle for you anyway

Comment: @Peanuts if it ends up being the official solution, don't forget to mark this one as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried

```
<li role="presentation pull-right"><a href="#">Admin Panel</a></li>
```

:P

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. That does not sound to be a solution to what the question asked.

Comment: I actually responded suggesting him to use the pull-right class and posted a code snippet, but then a screen showed up asking my if I was a robot and told me to click the captcha! And then this appeared. And firefox is all buggy now. I had to use chrome to post the comment.

Comment: That was my original comment. :S

Comment: Well, this is way far better! Good luck with your antivirus ;)